# how to do a sql self-join with group by without doing a full index scan

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, self-join

Apologies in advance if this has an answer elsewhere - I did look hard but couldn't find one.

I've got a table called 'item' which is a bit like this:

```
itemid applicationid value
   1        1        3.00
   2        2        1.00
   3        2        2.00
   4        3        4.00
   5        3        1.00
```

i.e. an application can have multiple items.  There are more columns but never mind.
I would like to list the items and their values against the total application value (so that I can work out the item value as a proportion of the application).

So I've got a query a bit like this:

```
SELECT i.itemid, i2.applicationid, i.value, i2.totalvalue
FROM item i
JOIN (SELECT sum(value) AS totalvalue FROM item GROUP BY applicationid) i2
    ON i.applicationid = i2.applicationid
WHERE <some criteria that returns a hundred or so items>;
```

to give me

```
itemid applicationid value totalvalue
   1        1        3.00     3.00
   2        2        1.00     3.00
   3        2        2.00     3.00
   4        3        4.00     5.00
   5        3        1.00     5.00
```

This works, but with 100k rows in the item table it is very, very slow.  I am told by my profiler that the problem is having a subquery that is doing a full index scan.

I wondered if a self-join with a GROUP BY would be quicker, but it groups the whole lot not just the second table.  I.e.

```
SELECT i.itemid, i2.applicationid, i.value, sum(i2.value)
FROM item i
JOIN item i2 ON i2.applicationid = i.applicationid
WHERE <some criteria that returns a hundred or so items>
GROUP BY i2.applicationid;
```

I only get 1 row per applicationid, not 1 row per itemid.

Is there any way to rewrite my original query that will make it quicker?

Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of SQL is this? What indexes are there defined on table's columns?

Comment: How much does it take to compute just `SELECT sum(value) AS totalvalue FROM item GROUP BY applicationid`?

Comment: Self-join is fine, and actually should be pretty quick. In your inner join, change your join to `JOIN (SELECT applicationid, sum(value) as totalvalue FROM item GROUP BY applicationid) i2 ON i2.applicationid = i.applicationid` and see if you get the same performance.

Comment: Kuba, it is MySQL and the item table has an index by applicationid.

Comment: Kuba, the subquery on its own is quick.

Comment: SPF, I initially neglected to write down the JOIN condition I'm using in my original query - I have added it now.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Your query has no join condition to the subquery, so it is not syntactically correct.  Have you tried this query:

```
SELECT i.itemid, i2.applicationid, i.value, i2.totalvalue
FROM item i JOIN
      (SELECT applicationid, sum(value) AS totalvalue
       FROM item
        GROUP BY applicationid
     ) i2
     on i.applicationid = i2.applicationid
WHERE <some criteria that returns a hundred or so items>;
```

In some databases, this might run faster as a correlated subquery, particularly if you have an index on applicationid:

```
SELECT i.itemid, i.applicationid, i.value,
       (select sum(value) from item i2 where i.applicationid = i2.applicationid
       ) as totalvalue
FROM item i JOIN
      (SELECT applicationid, sum(value) AS totalvalue
       FROM item
        GROUP BY applicationid
     ) i2
     on i.applicationid = i2.applicationid
WHERE <some criteria that returns a hundred or so items>;
```

Also, it could be your WHERE criteria that is slowing things down, once again, depending on the database.

Comment: My goodness, sorry, you are right Gordon - in simplifying the query for the post I neglected the join condition.  Your first query above is as I had it originally.  Your second version is slower for me.

Comment: I do have an index on applicationid.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using windowing functions to see if the optimizers uses them well. I would guess that it will use the same execution plan, but it is worth a quick try. This is the code for SQL Server, and it should be similar for Oracle.

```
SELECT i.itemid, i.applicationid, i.value, 
    sum(value) Over (Partition by i.applicationid) as totalvalue
FROM item i
WHERE <some criteria that returns a hundred or so items>;
```

Comment: Although I agree a window function would work, I'd be hesitant to use it on this much data. Window functions are an excellent tool, but I find they do not work well for large sets of data (they work, just slower).

Comment: I don't think I can do this in MySQL?